# Блокировка конкурентных действий в БД

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Каким способом можно сделать блокировку нескольких конкурентных действий в БД?

Сейчас использую advisory lock в postgres, но может быть есть какие-то другие решения? Например с использованием redis? Serializable не подходит по производительности.

Comment: Поддерживаю вопрос: как дела у баз данных с _пессимистическими_ (то есть, настоящими) блокировками?

Comment: @VladD, я так понимаю что явные блокировки типа LOCK TABLES не рассматриваются?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: О, не знал про эту возможность, спасибо! С моей точки зрения — ещё как рассматриваются, а вот то ли это, что хочет ТС, мне сложно судить. (В Entity Framework встроены оптимистические, но не пессимистические блокировки из коробки, это извиняет моё невежество в данном вопросе.)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов lock tables не подходит, т.к. мне не нужно локать все таблицы, а только определенные их части. 

Пессимистичные блокировки, если это то о чем я думаю, тоже не подходят. Мне нужен аналог мьютекса, только в базе. Чтобы клиенты "зависали" пока лок не пропадет и захватывали сразу когда мьютекс освободится. advisory lock как раз это и делает, но у него можно указать только два 32ух-битных ключа или один 64х-битный, а этого к сожалению не всегда хватает

Answer (score 1):

возможно вам подойдут самые обычные блокировки на уровне строки

http://postgrespro.ru/doc/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS

то есть выдав команду SELECT ... FOR UPDATE вы заблокируете до конца транзакции строки, которые были затронуты в команде SELECT. 
почитайте ссылку, там подробно и по русски всё написано.